# Convert a dictionary containing lists as values to a DataFrame

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a python dictionary like this:

```
tag_dict = {'001':['apple', 'orange'], '002':['banana', 'strawberry', 'peach']}
```

I want to transfer this dictionary to a DataFrame like below:

```
id  value
001 apple
001 orange
002 banana
002 strawberry
002 peach
```

There are two columns: 'id' and 'value'.

I have two rows with id 001, but different values in the 'value' column: 'apple' and 'orange'. Similarly for the id 002.

Comment: what have you attempted, how is it not working?

Comment: I tried the function in pandas package,pd. DataFrame.from_dict().

Comment: but it won't repeat the id , it turns into only two row. do you have any idea to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `DataFrame.from_dict()` you could follow it up with `stack()` and then the reset the index:

```
>>> tag_dict = {'001':['apple','orange'], '002':['banana','strawberry','peach']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tag_dict, orient='index').stack()
>>> df.reset_index(level=0)
  level_0           0
0     001       apple
1     001      orange
0     002      banana
1     002  strawberry
2     002       peach
```

You could then rename the columns and give it whatever index you like:

```
>>> df.columns = ['id', 'value']
>>> df.set_index('id')
          value
id             
001       apple
001      orange
002      banana
002  strawberry
002       peach
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works for me. and one more question, if i could let the id column to be index. thought i'll get a dataframe only have one column?

Comment: Glad it helped. You could write `df.set_index('id')` to set the id column as the index, then you'll have a DataFrame with only one column ('value').